# Unable to use the tilde sign (~) to filter DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this DataFrame `df`, I want to dump rows containing the word `Zmiana`.

```
                                      Event   Q
0  Zmiana - I. Zigeranovic ZEJSCIE D. Kulig   1
1      Zmiana - T. Taylor ZEJSCIE M. Taylor   1
2                                       NaN   1
3            L. Jeter - niecelny rzut wolny   1

df = df[~df.Event.str.contains('Zmiana').fillna(False)]  # tilde takes the opposite
```

This raised me `KeyError: '[-2 -2 -1 -1] not in index'` all because of the `NaN` row.

Ignoring whether it is a bug, do you know a workaround?

Comment: hmm; this seems to work in >= 0.13. what version of python/pandas are you using?

Comment: I guess I need the upgrade, I run 0.12

Comment: you can do this: ``df[df.val.str.contains('a').fillna(False).values ^ True]`` to make it work (numpy is more to blame here), FYI, all fixed in >= 0.13

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution, Jeff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dumb down your example a bit. What you basically have is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['aa', 'ab', 'c'], columns={'val'})
>>> df[df.val.str.contains('a').fillna(False)]
Out[737]: 
  val
0  aa
1  ab
>>> df[df.val.str.contains('a').fillna(False) == False]
Out[738]: 
  val
2   c
```

All that `contains()` returns is an array containing booleans - standard procedures are applicable.